# How to check is the paired bluetooth device available in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth

I faced following issue:
I need to check is the paired device via Bluetooth present and availbale to communicate.
When I start startInquiry method from DiscoveryAgent, it retrieves all available devices without paired ones

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hackish solution would be to start DiscoveryAgent.searchServices() for that paired device and if you don't get even a single service then you can say that the device is not available for communication.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/bluetooth/BluetoothSerialPort.html#getSerialPortInfo%28%29) returns only the paired devices.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but..OK I will receive the list of paired devices, but how can I check, are they near my local device, and are they available?